# Using VHDL Record in SystemVerilog Testbench in Modelsim

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog, modelsim

I've done research on this, but the examples that I've found on other web pages have broken links.  I'm looking for an example of how to import a custom VHDL record that is contained in a package into a SystemVerilog Testbench.

I'm using modelsim, so I've read that I need to use the `-mixedsvvh` switch.  Do I need to use this switch for both `vcom` and `vlog` calls?  Also, there's another switch `[b | s | v]` which when I use `s` it gives me an error:

> ** Error: (vcom-1276) Option '-mixedsvvh' was given with a bad argument.

When I use no arguments, I try to run `vsim` and I get the following message:

> -- Importing package c:/Projects/source/work.test_pkg__mti__sv__equiv__implct__pack
>   ** Error: Test_Top_TB.sv(4): 't_Test' is an unknown type.

### VHDL Package:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package test_pkg is
  type t_Test is record
    DATA1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    DV1   : std_logic;
    DATA2 : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    DV2   : std_logic;
  end record t_Test;
end package test_pkg;
```

### VHDL Entity/Architecture:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library work;
use work.test_pkg.all;

entity Test_Top is
  port (
    i_Clk  : in  std_logic;
    i_Data : in  t_Test;
    o_Data : out t_Test
    );
end entity Test_Top;

architecture RTL of Test_Top is
begin
  process (i_Clk) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(i_Clk) then
      o_Data.DATA1 <= i_Data.DATA1;
      o_Data.DV1   <= i_Data.DV1;
      o_Data.DATA2 <= i_Data.DATA2;
      o_Data.DV2   <= i_Data.DV2;  
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture RTL;
```

### SystemVerilog Testbench:

```
interface Test_IF();
  import test_pkg::*;

  t_Test Data;
endinterface // Test_IF

module Test_Top_TB ();
  import test_pkg::*;
  logic r_Clock;
  Test_IF hook();
  Test_IF hook2();
  Test_Top UUT 
    (.i_Clk(r_Clock),
     .i_Data(hook.Data),
     .o_Data(hook2.Data)
     );
endmodule
```

Comment: @dave_59, You've answered this question at least twice: https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/vhdl-record-systemverilog-struct and http://www.verificationguild.com/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=3102&view=previous but on both of those pages the link to the example is broken.

Comment: I don't see any links to examples on the pages you mentioned. Have you looked int the Questa install directory <>/examples/mixedlang for sample scripts?

Comment: @dave_59, ah, that's where you meant... I didn't know those were there.  Thanks.  Also on the 2nd link, your last post says, "The Details are Posted Here" but the link is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing `t_Test` in your `systemverilog` testbench to lower case, ie. `t_test`.

Comment: That got it.  Also for whoever has this same problem in the future, I didn't need to use any of the switches after `-mixedsvvh`, just using that during the compile was enough.